# How do I debug generic methods in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, generics

I'm in a generic method, debugging, but i get no information about variables, can't execute statements using ctrl-shift-i, eclipse tells the that the method ... isn't available on the type T.

I can't believe it's meant to (not) work like this ...

[edit]

I'm using the eclipse that's part of RAD 7.5.4

[another edit]

Here's some code but I doubt you'll get any info from this

```
   public abstract class GenericGroupController<T extends Group> {
   ...

    public String addUser(final Model model, final Long id, final WebRequest request) {

        T group = groupManager.loadGroup(id);

        ...
        // this method will fail if i highlight and click ctr-shift-i
        // but it will work otherwise (actually so will the method above
        // because that's generic as well)
        Long groupId =  group.getId(); 
        ...

        return getAddUserView();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I know, it should work. Recently I debugged such a method, and I don't remember seeing such problems. Can you elaborate, or possibly provide a snippet that provides this issue?

Comment: Please provide your eclipse installation details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to debug, as in see a stack trace, you can always see the variables in the variables window if not in the code. A lot of places where the code isn't available you can do the same. It isn't nice, but, it gets the job done.

Comment: Might sound mundane, but, did you try setting the source on your debugger? Sometimes I see that eclipse doesn't show me the class even though I have the sources attached to the project.